# Persistent ROW LOCK after a function or stored procedure call

Tags: sql-server

I have two scenarios where a datetime value is returned to a calling application.  The first scenario uses a function, the second scenario uses a stored procedure with an output parameter.  Using either works fine.  Is it possible to lock the row that has the datetime value, preventing any additional reads, so that the lock persists after the value has been returned to the calling application?  I have a table with a date column and a time column.  For every date there are ten rows for times 15 minutes apart:

```
+------------+----------+
| Date       | Time     |
+------------+----------+
| 10/12/2019 | 12:00:00 |
+------------+----------+
| 10/12/2019 | 12:15:00 |
+------------+----------+
| 10/12/2019 | 12:30:00 |
+------------+----------+
```

So, let's say either the function or the stored procedure finds the row containing `10/12/2019   12:15:00`.  Is it possible to lock this row and leave it locked after the function or stored procedure has finished it's job by returning the datetime value back to the calling application?  The calling application would then make another function or stored procedure call to SQL Server afterwards to unlock the row when it's work is done.  Any ideas?  Maybe a CLR Stored Procedure could handle things?   Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: YOU MAY USE CASE STATEMENTS IN SQL.

Comment: Short answer - no (or very unlikely but is highly dependent on your code). Longer answer - this is exactly the type of thing a OLTP tries to avoid. Search pessimistic vs. optimistic locking. An application lock might be one approach to try.

Comment: Use transactions?